# SQL: get Nth item in each group

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a user table like this

```
user_id | community_id | registration_date
--------------------------------------------
1       |     1        | 2008-01-01
2       |     1        | 2008-05-01
3       |     2        | 2008-01-28
4       |     2        | 2008-07-22
5       |     3        | 2008-01-11
```

For each community, I would like to get the time that the 3rd user registered. I can easily do this for a single community using MySql's 'limit' SQL extension. For example, for community with ID=2

```
select registration_date
from user
order by registration_date
where community_id = 2
limit 2, 1
```

Alternatively, I can get the date that the first user registered for all communities via:

```
select community_id, min(registration_date) 
from user 
group by 1
```

But I can't figure out how to get the registration date of the 3rd user for *all* communities in a single SQL statement.

Cheers,
Don

Answer (score 2):

With an inner select:

```
select 
  registration_date, community_id 
from 
  user outer 
where 
  user_id IN (
    select 
      user_id 
    from 
      user inner 
    where 
      inner.community_id = outer.community_id 
    order by 
      registration_date 
    limit 2,1
  )
order by registration_date
```

Selects the set of users where each user is the 3rd user in their community as returned by the limit clause in the inner select.

Comment: This doesn't work because the inner select may return more than one value. The version of MySql I'm using doesn't permit a LIMIT to be used inside an inner select, so I can't simply replace the "=" with an "IN"

Comment: Ah, yeah, old versions of MySQL can be a pain to work with.  I'm not sure what you can do if you can't LIMIT the inner select.

Comment: You probably have to break it out into multiple statements due to the limitations of your version.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
SELECT registration_date
FROM user
ORDER BY registration_date
LIMIT n
```

Where *n* is the user you are concerned about.

Comment: No, I want to get the Nth user registration date for each community